# Expand indicator (Arrow) is missing for two topics at chat faq

Tags: bug, chat-faq

On the [chat faq](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) there are some topics which are expandable (i.e having `show more` links) which have arrow ▶ at end of title that indicates that it is expandable but there are two topics - "How do I talk?" and "How do I format my messages?" which are expandable and also have `show more` link but the arrows ▶ is missing at the end of title.

[image: expected]

Note: This is not (Don't consider it to be) a serious issue or problem an may be given a less priority.

Comment: Btw, there is also another minor issue which I've discussed in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5150691#5150691)